# How to convert all source code to dex file [Android Decomplie]

Tags: android, apk, decode

I have some problems with my project. I lost all source code yesterday, I have apk that signed and uploaded to google play. Now I need to decode apk file to get all source code back. After that, I want to change some feature in source code class. then I want to compile that source code to apk and send to my customer.I have try some tool to get my source code ,   I decoded I gotten  70% source code ( Thank God !) . I need to stay and type rest of it then compile. It's hard to do this. So I continute researching.. I read about that Apktool can help me in get source code then decompile to apk. But I can not find out way to get source, apktool just get xml for me. So I stuck with this.

I need some help for me, for my project. 
Thank inadvance!

Comment: Wow, I feel bad for you. :( Don't forget to use backups, this is why!